# How Can I use a custom view with popup view controller

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I have made a Popupview on a standard NSView. The Popup appears-OK. But I would like to show a programmatically created view. So I set the view of the view delegate of the popupViewController.

```
NSView* editorView = [self.sharedUI editorViewForElementKey:classKey];// Creates a custom view and its subviews
self.popoverViewController.view  = editorView;  programmatically
[[self editorPopover]showRelativeToRect:[elementViewItem] ofView:elementViewItem preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge]; // shows the View.
```

The Popup appears and it seems that the window-size is the size of my newly generated view, but it is empty.

To generate my 'editorView' I used a derived Class and generate my Subviews with:

```
NSView *view;
view = [[NSTextField alloc]initWithFrame:control.rect];
((NSTextField*)view).stringValue = control.controlAttributeName;   
[((NSTextField*)view) setBezeled:NO];
[((NSTextField*)view) setDrawsBackground:NO];
[((NSTextField*)view) setEditable:NO];
[((NSTextField*)view) setSelectable:NO];   
[self addSubview:view];
```

what do I make wrong? Am I overseeing something?

Comment: I noticed if I place a custom view in the popup's nib file and add some NSTextFields to this view, they will be displayed. Is there something wrong with the order? Must my custom View be 'live' on the popup's nib file?

Comment: What is self.popoverViewController? Is it an NSViewController instance? If so, I'd expect an error when trying to set its view, since this isn't a property but a convenient way of asking for the view it was created with.

Comment: PopoverViewController is the default Popover View Controller which is derived from NSviewController. You are right: .view is not a Property. Maybe using setView leads to success. 
I ended up with handling the Popovers View instance directly and not creating a new one.

Comment: Well, no ... the correct course of action is to create the view controller *with* the view. You don't set a view controller's view after it's been created/established.